# Processing large zip files with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, parallel-processing, stream

I have a web service Rest running Java Spring boot, my controller is running in POST and take a zip file in MultipartFile and then processed on the web service.
The web service first reloads the zip file on a disk and then processes it backend.
Everything works well with this simple architecture,
The problem is :
1-with parallel processing of .zip files (I have to handle several .zip at the same time)
2- large files. > 1GB

**My question :**
is it possible to treat several instances on the same web service?
is it possible to process the zip in real time without loading it into the disk? 
What is the best way to treat this type of treatment? Thank you for your suggestions